# how to remove the first row of some of the group's elements?

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I  have 3 columns: the index of household,the number of members of each family , the number of trips for each person and the trip's location. I want the location of first trip of each person in each family to be home. here is an example:

```
  Household  person  trip     location
      1         1     1          home
      1         1     2          work
      1         1     3          home
      1         2     1          other
      1         2     2          home
      1         2     3          work
      2         1     1          school
      2         1     2          home
      2         1     3          shopping
      2         1     4          home
```

the first trip of the second person in first household is other, so I want to remove this row and I want trip column change as well and start from 1. 
second household has one member and first trip is school so i want to remove this row as well and change trip column so I want the output to be:

```
  Household  person  trip     location
      1         1     1          home
      1         1     2          work
      1         1     3          home
      1         2     1          home
      1         2     2          work
      2         1     1          home
      2         1     2          shopping
      2         1     3          home
```

Comment: Could you add sample code that has already failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` is to `group_by` `Household` and `person` and `slice` row from where the value is `"home"` till end of the group. We can then add new trip number to each group using `row_number`. This assumes that every group would have at least one `"home"` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Household, person) %>%
  slice(which.max(location == "home") : n()) %>%
  mutate(trip = row_number())

#  Household person  trip location
#      <int>  <int> <int> <fct>   
#1         1      1     1 home    
#2         1      1     2 work    
#3         1      1     3 home    
#4         1      2     1 home    
#5         1      2     2 work    
#6         2      1     1 home    
#7         2      1     2 shopping
#8         2      1     3 home
```

Comment: how about if I want to remove last trip of each person if it is not home? in that case we do not need to change trip's number!

Comment: @sherek_66 In that case, you can do something like `df %>%
  group_by(Household, person) %>%
  slice(if(location[n()] != "home") 1:(n() - 1) else 1:n())
`

Comment: I found you the smartest in dataframe do you have any solution for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245666/how-pick-some-elements-of-a-group-who-have-some-relation-with-each-other-other/57245762#57245762

Comment: could you please tell me if doing this question is impossible in R or not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259022/finding-overlapping-time-in-each-group-of-data-set/57259494?noredirect=1#comment101018616_57259494

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Household', 'person', get the cumulative sum of logical expression and subset the data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[cumsum(location == "home")> 0], .(Household, person)
         ][, trip := rowid(Household, person)]
#  Household person trip location
#1:         1      1    1     home
#2:         1      1    2     work
#3:         1      1    3     home
#4:         1      2    1     home
#5:         1      2    2     work
#6:         2      1    1     home
#7:         2      1    2 shopping
#8:         2      1    3     home
```

---

Or the same with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Household, person) %>% 
    filter(cumsum(location == "home") > 0) %>%
    mutate(trip = row_number())
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Household, person [3]
#  Household person  trip location
#      <int>  <int> <int> <chr>   
#1         1      1     1 home    
#2         1      1     2 work    
#3         1      1     3 home    
#4         1      2     1 home    
#5         1      2     2 work    
#6         2      1     1 home    
#7         2      1     2 shopping
#8         2      1     3 home
```

---

If we want to remove the `last` trip if not 'home'

```
df %>%
    group_by(Household, person) %>%
    filter(row_number() != n()| last(location) == "home") 
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Household, person [3]
#  Household person  trip location
#      <int>  <int> <int> <chr>   
#1         1      1     1 home    
#2         1      1     2 work    
#3         1      1     3 home    
#4         1      2     1 other   
#5         1      2     2 home    
#6         2      1     1 school  
#7         2      1     2 home    
#8         2      1     3 shopping
#9         2      1     4 home
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    trip = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), location = c("home", 
    "work", "home", "other", "home", "work", "school", "home", 
    "shopping", "home")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```