# how pick some elements of a group who have some relation with each other other?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column for household. I have another for member of household, and another column for mode of travel for them. This column is 1 or 2. 1 if a person is driver and 2 if person is passenger. I have determine who is driver of which passenger. So, I need to use other information to determine that. I have a column for start time and a column for duration of trip. So driver i gives a ride to passenger j, if they have the same start and duration time. If it is complicate to work with 2 columns start time is enough.

Here is an example

```
    Household    person   mode    start_time      duration_time
       1           1        1          8:25              10
       1           1        1          16:00             20
       1           2        2          8:25              10
       1           3        2          16:00             20
       2           1        1          15:00              4
       2           1        2          20:00              20
       2           2        2          15:00              4
       2           2        1          20:00              20
```

So I need some thing which show that the index of passenger in the same row as driver. the rows of passenger can be just the index of passengers themselves lves like this:

```
    Household    person   mode    start_time      duration_time passenger
       1           1        1          8:25              10.       2
       1           1        1          16:00             20        3
       1           2        2          8:25              10        2
       1           3        2          16:00             20        3
       2           1        1          15:00              4        2
       2           1        2          20:00              20.      1
       2           2        2          15:00              4        2
       2           2        1          20:00              20       1
```

or the row of passengers can be eliminated and we have

```
    Household    person   mode.    start time.      duration time. passenger
       1           1        1          8:25              10.       2
       1           1        1          16:00             20        3
       2           1        1          15:00              4        2
       2           2        1          20:00              20       1
```

any help?

how about if I have the trips number and I want to keep passenger's trip number?

```
    Household    person  mode    start_time      duration_time trip
       1           1        1          8:25              10.       1 
       1           1        1          16:00             20        2
       1           2        2          8:25              10        1
       1           3        2          16:00             20        1
       2           1        1          15:00              4        1
       2           1        2          20:00              20.      2
       2           2        2          15:00              4        1
       2           2        1          20:00              20       2
```

and the output

```
    Household    person   mode.    start time.      duration time. passenger  trip 
       1           1        1          8:25              10.           2       1
       1           1        1          16:00             20            3       1
       2           1        1          15:00              4              2       1
       2           2        1          20:00              20             1       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided data at this point, here is my suggestion for you. Your data is called `mydf`. Note that `start_time` is character now. I defined groups using `Household`, `start_time` and `duration_time`. Then, I created a character string including `person`. The first number in the string indicates driver. If necessary, you want to modify the final result.

```
library(tidyverse)

group_by(mydf, Household, start_time, duration_time) %>%
summarize(person = paste(person[order(mode)], collapse = "-")) %>%
ungroup

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  Household start_time duration_time person
#      <int> <chr>              <int> <chr> 
#1         1 16:00                 20 1-3   
#2         1 8:25                  10 1-2   
#3         2 15:00                  4 1-2   
#4         2 20:00                 20 2-1
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
person = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), mode = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), start_time = c("8:25", "16:00", 
"8:25", "16:00", "15:00", "20:00", "15:00", "20:00"), duration_time = c(10L, 
20L, 10L, 20L, 4L, 20L, 4L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

EDIT

If you want to include the `trip` information, you can try the following with the data you provided.

```
group_by(mydf2, Household, start_time, duration_time) %>%
summarize(person = paste(person[order(mode)], collapse = "-"),
          trip = trip[mode == 2]) %>%
ungroup

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Household start_time duration_time person  trip
#      <int> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>  <int>
#1         1 16:00                 20 1-3        1
#2         1 8:25                  10 1-2        1
#3         2 15:00                  4 1-2        1
#4         2 20:00                 20 2-1        2
```

DATA

```
mydf2 <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
person = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), mode = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), start_time = c("8:25", "16:00", 
"8:25", "16:00", "15:00", "20:00", "15:00", "20:00"), duration_time = c(10, 
20, 10, 20, 4, 20, 4, 20), trip = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: if the first number is driver the second passenger in second family the trip starts at 20:00 the second person is driver and first is passenger, we should have 2-1

Comment: @sherek_66 Hi. I have a bit of hard time to understand your English. Let me clarify this. Does `mode` indicate whether a person is a driver (1) or a passenger (2)? If so, you want to reflect that information. Is that right?

Comment: @jazzurro May be the OP wants `mydf %>% group_by(Household, start_time, duration_time) %>% mutate(passenger = person[match(2, mode)])` and then `%>% filter(mode == 1)` returns the second output.  It is not clear though

Comment: @akrun Long time no speak. Thanks for the comment. I was doing my work and I could not reply to you. I think that is what the OP is asking. I modified my code to reflect what the OP said. We will see if this is enough.

Comment: @sherek_66 Sorry for taking some time. I needed to get a task done. I modified my code. I hope this is what you are after. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: if I have the trips number for persons in a column can I get number of trip of passenger as well?

Comment: @sherek_66 If you can provide a sample data, I am happy to help you. But I can do that after my work.

Comment: @sherek_66 Even when you have trip number as you indicated in your data, the principle is still the same. You just add `trip` in `group_by()`. They key point here is how to define group and create a column containing driver and passenger information.

Comment: @jazzurro when I add trip's column the output is not correct

Comment: @sherek_66 Why do you have 1 and 2 (trip number) in the opposite way for Household 2 in the output? That seems inconsistent given what you provided for the data. I cannot see the logic you have.

Comment: @sherek_66 Can you explain why you have 1 for the trip starting at 16:00 for Household 1?

Comment: person 3 is passenger and he has 1 trip. 1 is trip number of person 3

Comment: @sherek_66 Seeing the pattern you described, do you want to have the smallest number of trip in each group?

Comment: @sherek_66 I added a suggestion. Hope this helps you. I am off to bed. If you need further help, you want to consider asking another question. One more thing. You want to write up your questions in details. Otherwise, SO users do not know what you want clearly.

Answer (score 1):

We can `group_by` `Household`, `start_time` and `duration_time` and select `person` with `mode == 1` and `mode == 2` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Household,start_time, duration_time) %>%
  summarise(passenger = person[mode == 2], 
            person = person[mode == 1]) %>%
  mutate(mode = 1)

#  Household start_time duration_time passenger person  mode
#      <int> <chr>              <int>     <int>  <int> <dbl>
#1         1 16:00                 20         3      1     1
#2         1 8:25                  10         2      1     1
#3         2 15:00                  4         2      1     1
#4         2 20:00                 20         1      2     1
```